# Laravel 5.1 - Refresh page on Ajax Navigation

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

In my app i have configured my navigation with `ajax`, so i can get my view's content (so only pure HTML) very quickly.
I've also implemented javascript's `history`, so i can modify url on navigation.

But when i refresh the page on a url like `my-app-/news`, of course i get the same content asked by ajax: the view with only html, but in this case i need a complete view, not only the content.

route.php

```
Route::get('/', 'PagesController@index');
Route::get('/{page}', 'PagesController@ajaxCall');
```

PagesController.php

```
class PagesController extends Controller {

    public function index(){
        return view('pages.index');
    }

    public function ajaxCall($page){
        return view('content.'.$page)->render();
    }

}
```

How to create another route and method like my index where i can call the full view on page refresh?

Comment: Because those methods will only return the response to the ajax call, and not a response to the browser telling it to switch pages. If you return a view with a 200, or even a 302, it's only going to be the ajax requester that sees it, not the browser

Comment: True, in fact i don't understand how to solve this

Comment: Just to prevent confusion, this is my Javascript: http://pastebin.com/1xp3JNLJ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can detect if the request was made via AJAX:

```
class PagesController extends Controller {

    public function index(){
        return view('pages.index');
    }

    public function ajaxCall($page){

        if(\Request::ajax()) {
           return view('content.'.$page)->render();
        } else {
           return ... //complete view
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: There's no data being sent to the server so why would you post? It's a request for a view, so it should be get. Maybe I'm misunderstanding your answer

Comment: Yes, i'm requesting a view, not just data

Comment: Switched to a more simple method.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds very difficult.

The term 'ajax' is very trivial. What do you use? jQuery, AngularJS?

In your case, it's great to separate front-end and back-end. Use for example AngularJS (*Single Page App*!) that connects with your Laravel/Lumen back-end. Your back-end has to return json results only (*RESTful controllers)*.

Read this documentation: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#restful-resource-controllers

Why? I notice that you've troubles because mixing front-end and back-end. With for example AngularJS, you make a single page app. With routing, you can (re)load specific parts of the 'page'. It's also very easy to connect to the Laravel/Lumen API en handle the json output in your SPA. Your back-end has no (html) views and doesn't do redirects.

Nice example: https://scotch.io/tutorials/create-a-laravel-and-angular-single-page-comment-application

Comment: You're right. Unfortunately i still don't have an advanced knowledge about Angular, so i created this app with jQuery.